# Ng-click not firing in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Here I created sample angular program  for button click. but its not firing 
may i know where i did mistake? can any one help me on this..
thanks

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.buttonHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml("<button ng-click='showMessage(\"foo\")'>click me</button>");
    $scope.showMessage = function(message) {
        alert(message);
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="buttonHtml"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you paste _html_ that not compiled angular, that's why ng-click attribute not work

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that even though the html renders nicely, Angular hasn't actually bound the `ng-click` to the `scope`, to do this you have to [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) it first.

```
var compiledHtml = $compile("<button ng-click='showMessage(\"foo\")'>click me</button>")($scope);
```

Comment: While using $compile is the correct approach, $compile returns a link function which after applying on the relevant scope returns DOM elements (and not strings).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compile & link the element with the correct scope and replace the "old element". This should be done with a directive:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div replace-with-compiled-html="buttonHtml"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.buttonHtml = "<button ng-click='showMessage(\"foo\")'>click me</button>";

  $scope.showMessage = function(message) {
    alert(message);
  }
});

myApp.directive('replaceWithCompiledHtml', function($compile) {
  return {
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      return {
        post: function preLink(scope, elem, iAttrs, controller) {
          // use the inherited scope -> get the wanted property via the attributes
          var scopePropName = iAttrs['replaceWithCompiledHtml'];

          // compile the html
          var linkingFunc = $compile(scope[scopePropName]);

          // link it with the correct inherited scope
          linkingFunc(scope, function(newElem) {
            // replace the new compiled element with the previous one
            elem.replaceWith(newElem);
          });
        }
      };
    }
  }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n3f9hLhq/).